# Eclipse plugin for generating UML diagram from c++ code

Tags: c++, eclipse, diagram

Is there any eclipse plugin that can generate UML/Class Diagram from C++ source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [list of UML tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Unified_Modeling_Language_tools), I only see commercial UML editors (with C++ as one of the language reverse engineered), like:

- [Enterprise Architect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparx_Systems#Sparx_Enterprise_Architect)
- [Magic Draw](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MagicDraw)
- [Modelio](http://www.modeliosoft.com/)

In other word, I don't know of a open-source project offering C++ reverse engineered UML diagrams.

---

[nrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1350116/nrs) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155448/eclipse-plugin-for-generating-uml-diagram-from-c-code/3155607?noredirect=1#comment36242717_3155607), from the [Modelio Wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelio):

> The core Modelio software was released under the GPLv3 on October 5, 2011.
>   Key APIs are licensed under the more permissive Apache License 2.0.

Note: [it is a standalone app](http://www.modelio.org/forum/7-general-help/895-how-to-use-modelio-from-eclipse.html) (based on Eclipse RCP), which cannot be added directly in your IDE Eclipse.
 Eclipse as a plugin.

Comment: @Tristan: I thought you wouldn't. I have edited my answer with its logical conclusion.

Comment: "The core Modelio software was released under the GPLv3 on October 5, 2011.[1] Key APIs are licensed under the more permissive Apache License 2.0." from Wikipedia

Comment: @nrs good point. I have included it in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 7):

This is also not a Eclipse plugin, but the [Umbrello UML Modeller](http://uml.sourceforge.net/index.php) from KDE is open-source and I've had better results with it than Doxygen or Rhapsody.

Comment: Shame it is only Linux that is natively supported.

Comment: @Konrad: you could try the unstable ports mentioned on the front page if you need another platform.

Comment: This one rocks! Works great on recent Linux platforms (such as Fedora 19)!

Answer (score 1):

My Eclipse-Fu is second to... well, everybodies.  But I wonder: Could Doxygen be banged in to a shape that would fit?  As an automated c++ documentation tool it's pretty slick.  Plus, it runs off the command line so I'd imagine it wouldn't be too tough to get eclipse to run it.

Comment: yes, I totally agree with you. Moreover, given the slowness of eclipse of what it is already working on in the background. It is hard that it could beat Doxygen.

Answer (score 0):

well, a commercial option is to use rhapsody developer for C++. you do reverse engineering in your source code and there you go.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any Eclipse Plugins that generates UML class diagram from C++ code. However,  BOUML is now commercial, but version 4 was free. You can still find this version in several repos of Linux distributions, it has the best reverse engineering features I've ever seen in a free application. It runs on Windows too, you can still find the [installer of BOUML 4 for Windows](http://www.chip.de/downloads/Bouml_42660800.html) on the Internet.