# Reverse C++ source to UML Class Diagram

Tags: c++, reverse-engineering, class-diagram

I would like to generate a C++ program to a Class Diagram using MacOS.

I've tried Doxygen (that many suggested in other topics in stackoverflow), but I don't seem to get how it works.

Could you suggest an easier solution? Which is the friendliest to the user program that offers an automated reverse to Class Diagram?

(For example something like what NetBeans 6.5.1 does for Java programs)

Comment: What are your particular problems with doxygen?

Comment: @g-makulik I just don't get how it works. It can't read the file that includes the source code I want to generate to a Class Diagram.

Comment: @Griwes Well excuse me sir, but this is my first time.

Comment: @felice, doxygen is one of the easiest tools for getting any form of documentation; it even provides GUI to configure it. If you cannot figure how to use it, then I think you are not ready for doing anything in C++... //damn those moderators removing perfectly legitimate comment...

Comment: @Griwes I want this for a project, I am not trying to become an expert. Like I said in a comment above, the problem is, it can't read the file that includes the source code I want to generate to a Class Diagram. I don't seem to solve this so I am just looking for an easier solution.

Comment: @felice What exactly means 't can't read the file'? Usually doxygen uses directories as input source.

Comment: @g-makulik It says that the directory I use is not readable. I don't know why...I checked many times and it's the right one.

Comment: @felice So how do you launch doxygen? Using the GUI? Might it be that you're having an access rights problem?

Comment: @g-makulik Yes, I use the GUI, I choose the directories and then I hit run.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using eclipse as an IDE, you could try the answers to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3155448/eclipse-plugin-for-generating-uml-diagram-from-c-code) post.

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly try to avoid the doxygen GUI. From terminal, enter  your source folder then type

```
 $ doxygen -g  #that generates the doxygen config file "doxyfile"
 $ doxygen
```

The latter generates two folders for the HTML and PDF versions of the UML.

the work is done!

you can edit doxyfile to change settings.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use Understand for C++ to generate UML or to re-factor code:

http://www.scitools.com/index.php